# Ubuntu Desktop systems freeze very often

Tags: esx

I have 2 ESXi hosts for 2 years dedicated, mainly, to VDI desktops. I have worked with Ubuntu Desktops from version 16.04.1.

From 2 weeks ago to now every VM I installed Ubuntu Desktop on freezes very often, especially when I browse any web page via Firefox.

I don't know what happens, Syslog doesn't indicate any error, the VM freezes and that's it, I have to power it off. It happens with 16.04.2, 16.04.3 and even 17.10; with and without VMWare Tools/Open-VM-Tools-Desktop installed, with any amount of memory and CPU.

It happens too even with no updates installed on the base image.

Any clue? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this is to install kernel 4.4.X (at the moment 4.4.0-98) instead of 4.10.X installed by 16.4.03 distribution.

It seems there has to be an issue with this kernel and virtual machines....

Regards,